# Prove polynomial and verification

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we have a polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+...a_1x+a_0$ where $a_i$ is in real number,  $i$ is between $0$ and $n$. Prove that $f(z)=0$ implies $f(\overline z)=0$

Then let $f(x)=x^4+4$. Verify that $f(1+i)=0$. Then find the other three roots from $1+i$

So I found $f(\overline z)= \bar (a_nZ^n+...a_1Z+a_0)$ which is $f(\bar z)$
thus $\bar f(z) = f(\bar z)$. If one of those is 0 then the other one is 0.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do include that in your post. For eg if the first part is done, can you do the second part yourself?

Comment: Surprisingly, I can't find the first part as a duplicate on math.stackexchange.com. Do you know the result $\bar{z}^n=\bar{z^n}$?

Comment: @Macavity I just edited what I did so far.

Comment: @Element118 No I don't know the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we note that for any two complex numbers $x, y$, we have from first principles,
$$\overline{x+y} = \overline x + \overline y, \quad \overline{x\cdot y} = \overline x \cdot \overline y$$
Using these, we may show (say by induction) that for any polynomial $p(z)$ with all coefficients real, $\overline {p(z)} = p(\overline z)$.   Thus in the problem we have
$$f(z) = 0 \implies \overline{f(z)} = \overline 0 = 0 \implies f(\overline z) = 0$$

Therefore, if $1+i$ is a root, so must be $\overline{1+i} = 1-i$.  So $z-(1+i)$ and $z-(1-i)$ are both factors, hence their product $z^2-2z+2$ must be a factor.  Dividing this out, we have
$$z^2+4 = (z^2-2z+2)(z^2+2z+2)$$
so the remaining roots are from the second quadratic, viz. $-1\pm i$.